# SQL Server is timing out on queries, but toggling settings on the database temporarily fixes the issue

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ssms

In my ASP.NET MVC web app, we are using Entity Framework to connect to a SQL Server database. We have noticed that some queries are timing out, but going into SSMS and changing Auto Shrink Off fixes the issue. After a few minutes, the queries start timing out again. Going back into SSMS and toggling Auto Shrink back On fixes the issue and the queries start working again. But again, after a few minutes the queries start timing out again.

What is SQL Server doing when it toggles Auto Shrink on and off and why would that have an impact on the queries that are timing out?

Comment: You should turn auto shrink off and leave it off. https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/auto-shrink-enabled/ If you have issues with your query performance you need to determine the cause of the performance problem.

Comment: That link is actually where I started. I was trying to improve performance and every time I made a change (Auto Shrink, Auto Update Stats Async, etc), the database started performing great! But then after 30 minutes or so, it would start running slowly again.

Comment: Then you need to evaluate the query. Look at the execution plan. The plan is going to give you the best details about where the problem comes from.

Comment: It is also possible that you are out of resources.

Comment: It appears that changing Auto Shrink wipes out the query execution plans. Checking `select * from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` after changing the setting shows that the QEPs are wiped out. Apparently my underlying issue is a bad QEP, or maybe too many QEP are being created (because too many stored procedures) and the server is running out of memory. Could be because of Skip and Take generate a new compiled query for every value. (https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/entity-framework-performance-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/)